# Equivalent to Sysinternals Process Explorer on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-rec, process-explorer, sysinternals

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and am looking for an equivalent to [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) on Linux. There is System Monitor but it's not nearly as good as Process Explorer with all of its detailed information about processes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you don't mind something that's terminal based, then [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) is a good and powerful process manager.

[image: htop screenshot]

You can install it on Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo aptitude install htop
```

If you prefer something with a GUI, you could try [qps](http://www.student.nada.kth.se/~f91-men/qps/).

[image: qps screenshot]

You can install it with the following:

```
sudo aptitude install qps
```

Comment: htop is good , but its not the most user friendly program !

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Qps is much better and is easier to use ,  I just wish it would show the icon of the Process if available , but still its very good

Comment: Is there tool that can show call-stack of a running thread?

Comment: It should be noted that Ubuntu 12.04 is the last Ubuntu release that has qps in its default repositories.

Comment: Unfortunately compared to Process Explorer  htop is a total toy not worth to use for debugging. Can't show loaded DLL's, open file handles etc.

Comment: @karel It is currently supported, and in the [default repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qps).

Comment: `qps` uses a lot of RAM (118-140MB) compared to Linux Process Explorer (~32MB), and MATE System Monitor (~11MB).

Comment: ...and in fact qps has already [been reported](https://github.com/lxqt/qps/issues/101) to have memory leaks.

Answer (score 14):

Use [Linux Process Explorer](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/procexp).

> Graphical process explorer for Linux. Shows process information:
>   process tree, TCP IP connections and graphical performance figures for
>   processes. Aims to mimic Windows procexp from sysinternals, and aims
>   to be more usable than top and ps.

[image]

**PS**. it is still in **alpha** development stage.

Comment: This looks like a useful tool, but your answer provides very little information about it. Could you edit your answer to include some info about how it works and perhaps a screenshot?

Comment: This looks great! htop and qps are well-established tools, but they don't display per-process history of CPU and memory usage. The Windows Process Explorer has a lot of useful features that I would be happy to find in a unix tool.

Comment: it lacks sorting or finding a process. if you have tons of processes, you can't locate yours.

Comment: @BerryTsakala typical linux programmers will write a process explorer without even the basic features of windows task manager! anything a linux programmer does with a gui, is a gimmick, i'm sure they dont even use what they write!

Comment: I love "kill process tree"!!!

Comment: I hate showing processes without icons and some more description than name...

Comment: "PS. it is still in alpha development stage..." since 2011?

Comment: As of January 1, 2022, it was last updated on November 24, 2018 at https://github.com/wolfc01/procexp/blob/master/README.md. Anyway, this looks pretty dead.

Answer (score 6):

gnome-system-monitor

(although i don't know what the OP needed 3 years ago)

gives almost everything that "top" has, but graphical, sortable columns, find open files, and more.

Few screenshots:

[image]

Resources tab:

[image]

Comment: Better `sudo apt-get install ksysguard`.