# how to find the specific program that's running on a process？

Tags: ubuntu

I am using a remote machine where all users share the same user name 'root'. When I use the 'top' command to check what users are running what processes, programs, it shows that all are running under the user 'root'. I don't know which one is my process.

Is there a way to check a process by the running program, instead of users? For example, if I start my 'test.py' through the 'root' user, how can I check whether 'test.py' is still running after a while?

I am on Ubuntu system.

Comment: any particular OS?

Comment: I am on Linux, ubutnu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are the only one that is running the `test.py` you could do a `ps -ef |grep test.py`

another way could be executing `ps -auxf`

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, Process Explorer can identify the application that a process is running under.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: I am using Ubutnu, please.

Comment: Ah, sorry, can't help in that case.
But I found this other question that might help you. https://superuser.com/questions/285572/equivalent-to-sysinternals-process-explorer-on-linux